# Why can't PHP insert new geometry on PostGIS?

Tags: php, postgis, gdal, ogr

I'm using ogr2ogr to upload a GPX file to PostGIS.

When I do it on command line (Ubuntu 14.04), it works fine.

```
ogr2ogr -append -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=... dbname=... user=... password=..." 2016-04-26_15-32-01.xml
```

When I do it on PHP (5.5.9),

```
exec("ogr2ogr -append -f PostgreSQL PG:\"host=".HOST." dbname=".DATABASE." user=".USER." password=".PASSWORD."\" /var/www/html/plantas/gps/2016-04-26_15-32-01.xml 2>&1",$output,$retval);
```

it gives the following error:

```
ERROR 1: INSERT command for new feature failed.
ERROR: Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (4326)

Command: INSERT INTO "waypoints" ("wkb_geometry" , "ele", "time", "name", "cmt", "desc", "sym", "type", "gpxx_waypointextension", "wptx1_waypointextension", "ctx_creationtimeextension") VALUES ('010100000000008C76C2DF4EC00100C0A13A450E40'::GEOMETRY, 594, '2015/11/16 17:22:09+00', 'ROP_2904', '08-NOV-15 9:56:51
PONTO 60', '08-NOV-15 9:56:51
PONTO 60', 'Flag, Blue', 'user', ' SymbolAndName ', ' SymbolAndName ', ' 2015-11-16T17:22:09Z ') RETURNING "ogc_fid"
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer waypoints (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
```

What am I missing here?

EDIT

I tried Mike T suggestion:

```
$linha = "ogr2ogr -append -f PostgreSQL PG:\"host=".HOST." dbname=".DATABASE." user=".USER." password=".PASSWORD."\" -s_srs EPSG:4326 /var/www/html/plantas/gps/2016-04-26_15-32-01.xml 2>&1";
// or $linha = "ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:4326 -append -f PostgreSQL PG:\"host=".HOST." dbname=".DATABASE." user=".USER." password=".PASSWORD."\" /var/www/html/plantas/gps/2016-04-26_15-32-01.xml 2>&1";
exec($linha,$output,$retval);
```

to no avail:

```
ERROR 1: INSERT command for new feature failed.
ERROR: Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (4326)
```

What's really strange is that exactly the same command works on terminal. So I think PHP might have some issue, perhaps a missing library or permission?

EDIT 2

Now I'm seeing there are some installations where the user need to run

```
psql -d yourdatabase -f postgis.sql
```

In my computer I did only the

```
create extension postgis;
create extension postgis_topology;
```

Gonna see if that's the problem.

EDIT 3 - SOLVED!

I started it all again:

1. restored a previous database from backup;
2. `create extension postgis;`
3. `create extension postgis_topology;`
4. `ogr2ogr` from console creates additional tables (like `waypoints`);
5. after this I need to grant access in those additional tables to php/apache user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started it all again:

1. restored a previous database from backup;
2. `create extension postgis;`
3. `create extension postgis_topology;`
4. `ogr2ogr` from console creates additional tables (like `waypoints`);
5. after this I need to grant access in those additional tables to php/apache user.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your source layer does not have a spatial reference system (SRID=0).

With [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) you can try `-s_srs EPSG:4326` to override the source SRS.

Comment: @Rodrigo how about using `-a_srs` instead?

Comment: I tried all three: -a_srs, -t_srs and -s_srs. None worked.

Comment: @Rodrigo try moving the position of this near the beginning, since the order of arguments is sometimes very specific

Comment: Like in the commented line of my edit? I tried all three options (a, t and s) in every possible position. Always the same error.